# In Java3D can I limit the mouse to rotating a scene in only two axes?

Tags: java-3d

I'd like the mouse to be able to change the pitch of a scene and rotate the yaw but keep roll fixed at 0. Had a look around OrbitBehaviour and such but can't see anything obvious.

I could manually set roll to 0 when the mouse is released but that seems a real kludge and might cause screen flicker.

All ideas gratefully accepted :-)

Comment: I advise you to ask your question of the official JogAmp forum as only a few maintainers come on StackOverflow.